# wordpress drop down stays visible now while working correctly before

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, dropdown

The menu on my site http://www.frankgalan.be/nieuws/  stays visible at the menu item "media". This black box should be only shown on mouseover.

This worked fine in the past, no changes were done.

I already tried to put the position to relative, but did not work:

```
#nav li ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:8px 0 0;
    list-style:none;
    width:221px;
    position:relative;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the #nav li ul should be set to 
position: absolute, and then set 
display: to none

Then add a hover psuedo class to get the submenu to display on hover